# JFrame method prob

Tags: java, swing, constructor, actionlistener, mainclass

I am currently developing a small text-based game, and I keep getting an error...
I don't know how to fix it, since its my first time using `JFrame`. The problem is,
when I make the `ButtonDemo` method into `ButtonDemo()`, not `public static void ButtonDemo()`, there is a problem with the `ButtonDemo()`. However, if it is `public static void ButtonDemo()`, there would be an error on the `jbtnW.addActionListener(this)`, saying that I cannot use the "this" because the `ButtonDemo()` is `static`.

```
package game;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import game.Storylines.*;

public class Frame implements ActionListener{
    VillageDrengr shops = new VillageDrengr();

    static JLabel jlab;

    static JFrame jfrm = new JFrame("A Game");

    public static void ButtonDemo() {
        jfrm.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        jfrm.setSize(500, 350);
        jfrm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JButton jbtnW = new JButton("Equipment Shop");
        JButton jbtnP = new JButton("Potion Shop");

        jbtnW.addActionListener(this);
        jbtnP.addActionListener(this);

        jfrm.add(jbtnW);
        jfrm.add(jbtnP);

        jlab = new JLabel("Choose a Store.");
        jfrm.add(jlab);

        jfrm.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Equipment Shop")) 
            jlab.setText("You went in to the Equipment Shop.");
        else
            jlab.setText("You went in to the Potion Shop.");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ButtonDemo();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: So, what exactly **is** the problem that you have with the `ButtonDemo()` method? You only say that "there's a problem"... What's the error? Can you paste the stack trace?

Comment: Maybe you wanted a constructor instead of a method, then do `new ButtonDemo()` in the `main`. .. Constructor `public ButtonDemo() {}`

Answer (score 1):

You're getting an error

> non-static variable `this` cannot be referenced from a non-static context`.

What's happening is that `this` is referencing the `ActionListener` which isn't `static`.

A simple fix would be to make the `ButtonDemo` method non-static, and call the method from `main` like this

```
        public void ButtonDemo() {
        ....

        public void run() {
           new Frame().ButtonDemo();
        }
```

You instantiate the `Frame` class, and call the method. The error goes away.

Also you shouldn't name your class `Frame` as there is already an AWT `Frame` class. You may run into problem.

Also, follow Java naming convention, method names begin with lower case letters i.e. `buttonDemo()`. Without looking at your class name, I was totally confused thinking the `ButtonDemo()` was the class constructor.